# Design : Plywood table for computer

Tags: design, plywood, table-making

I am trying to make 5 by 2 computer table. For mentioned design what should be thickness of plywood?, also I am trying to adjust table in 8 by 4 plywood sheet.

Design:

[image: Design]

Measurements are in Foot, (12 Inch = 1 Foot)
Max weight on table : 80 KG - 100 KG

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: You've provided the cut diagram which is good, but I don't see how the cut pieces match up to the example photograph you've provided. It would be helpful to provide drawing(s) of the two different designs you're thinking about.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to make drawings, i.e which software to use and all. PS - first time I'm attempting this

Comment: There's always pencil & paper, just like your cut list...

Comment: @FreeMan, design 1 is closest to the photo but omits the stretcher (although easily modified to be basically the same by splitting the 'support' piece). Design 2 I'm presuming the top is just supported on three independent legs (one each side, one centrally towards/at the back?).

Comment: vijaysy, can you clarify the expected load? If you truly need the desk to support in excess of 80kg I would discard design 2 immediately as the legs will have far too much tendency to splay, and it will be very difficult or impossible to attach them to the top to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

> For mentioned design what should be thickness of plywood?

Most people would choose 3/4" (18mm) plywood for a project like this because it's thick enough to be relatively sturdy (1/2" plywood would flex too much for a desktop), and it's readily available (you can get a sheet at any home center). Other thicknesses, like 1 1/4", are available from specialty plywood dealers, and thicker material would certainly make a nice desk, but it'd also be heavier and more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

The default choice for many here would be 3/4" or 18mm plywood, but as in a lot of other applications that's for a range of reasons and *not* because it's the minimum thickness that is suitable.

Additional support provided for the top makes all the difference in desks of this basic type and I think both designs could easily be done in 1/2" or 13mm plywood if it's good quality.

**This assumes typical loads however**. The weight range given at the bottom of your cut diagram is by no means a typical load for a computer desk, even if you were planning on positioning the case on the top behind a large CRT monitor!

Answer (score 0):

A furniture/cabinet quality plywood @ 18mm/3/4" will serve you well.  Avoid lower grade subfloor/sheathing plywood.  If you use a hardwood edging (not iron/glue on) if will add a bit of rigidity as well.

If you find yourself with a lot of flex in the top, you can always double up the top with a second piece glued to the top.  Make this slightly overside and flush it up with a trim router.